# Join three tables having max(date) for rows of first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Partymain Table -- Partyid PK, Partyname

Smplanmain Table -- Smplanid PK, Smplandt

Smplandet Table -- Smplandetid PK, Smplanid FK, Partyid, slotno, elotno

Output -- Partyid, Partyname,Smplandt, Slotno, Elotno

I want to do left join on Partymain to get only one row for each party having max(smplandt).

```
Select Partymain.partyid,Partymain.partyname,Isnull(LastSample.smplandt,'') as smplandt_last,Isnull(LastSample.slotno,'') as slotno_last,IsNull(LastSample.elotno,'') as elotno_last
    from Partymain
    Left Join 
    (Select b.partyid,a.smplandt,b.slotno,b.elotno from Smplandet b Inner Join Smplanmain a On b.smplanid = a.smplanid
    ) as LastSample On Partymain.partyid = LastSample.partyid
        order by Upper(partyname)
```

The inner query is returning multiple rows. How to write the query so that it returns the row with max smplandt for each partyid.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking as per my understanding, if it is not wrong from your explanation Here's the query that should return only the maximum **Smplandt** value for each **partyid** in the Smplandet table:

```
SELECT pm.Partyid, pm.Partyname, sm.SmplanSmplandt AS smplandt_last, sd.slotno AS slotno_last, sd.elotno AS elotno_last
FROM Partymain pm
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT partyid, MAX(Smplandt) AS SmplanSmplandt
    FROM Smplandet sd
    INNER JOIN Smplanmain sm ON sd.Smplanid = sm.Smplanid
    GROUP BY partyid
) sm ON sm.partyid = pm.Partyid
LEFT JOIN Smplandet sd ON sd.Smplanid = (SELECT TOP 1 Smplanid FROM Smplanmain WHERE Smplandt = sm.SmplanSmplandt) AND sd.partyid = pm.Partyid
ORDER BY pm.Partyname
```

Comment: Yes I was looking for complete list of parties who were there + not there in Smplandet table. The previous answer gave me the list of parties who were there in Smplandet table. Your answer gave what I was looking for. I should have explained more lucidly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find row with MAX Smplandt value for given Partyid using [OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You need to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Smplandet.Partyid ORDER BY Smplanmain.Smplandt DESC) AS RowNumber` and later filter your result with `RowNumber = 1`. You can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or inner query to get rows with Row Number value and later apply WHERE condition on the result with `RowNumber = 1`.

Check the code below. I used [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get result with RowNumber values.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  Smplandet.Partyid,
            Partymain.Partyname,
            Smplanmain.Smplandt,
            Smplandet.slotno,
            Smplandet.elotno,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Smplandet.Partyid ORDER BY Smplanmain.Smplandt DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Smplandet
        LEFT JOIN Partymain ON Partymain.Partyid = Smplandet.Partyid
        LEFT JOIN Smplanmain ON Smplanmain.Smplanid = Smplandet.Smplanid
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```